# Как предсказать массив на основе другого массива?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Мне нужно предсказать массив используя нейронную сеть на основе данного массива. К примеру у меня есть массив

> [12,1,1,45,67,2,1,2]

, а в ответ от нейронной сети я должен получить, что-то вроде

> [20,3,3,10,30,1,1,1]

. Почитав я вроде понял что нужно использовать RNN или типа того, но вот конкретики я не нашёл. Подскажите статью или если знаете решение, то поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Слишком мало данных для использования нейросетей. Нейросеть легко "переобучится" на таком малом кол-ве данных. А вообще не очень понятна сама задача - вы хотите продолжить этот ряд чисел или что собственно сделать? Любая модель должна на чём-то учиться. Что у вас тут целевая переменная? Или это временной ряд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый  вопрос, который вы должны задать -  а связь между вашими данными действительно есть? И второй вопрос при работе с алгоритмами машинного обучения и в 100 раз более серьёзный при работе именно с нейросетями -  у вас есть пару тысяч примеров таких ВЗАИМОЗАВИСИМЫХ пар?
Вот вам и вся конкретика. А по одной паре выборок ничего никогда никакая нейросеть предсказать не способна.

P.S. Но если связь таки есть, то для данной задачи нейросеть может быть и ни к чему. Есть другие методы поиска "предсказания" ответа, которые часто оказываются  более простыми и более точными.